# What would be a good structure to store data for the given case in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, performance, data-structures

Users have to rate product/ service of a businesses. User should be able to come back and change their rating for this product.

Average rating = Total Stars/ Number of users who rated the product/ service

**The picture below might explain case here better.**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

A map would work.  You can define the map having a user for the key and service/product for data.  Updating their rating would not be a problem as it can be updated.